# can Pygame surface.fill and tkinter.colorchooser work together?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am just playing around with pygame, and I came to an idea to make a coloring app. i made the painting part pretty easly, but now I want to be able to change the color, and for that I tought it would be a good idea to use tkinters colorchooser. I made this function for that:

```
def color():
    c = colorchooser.askcolor()[0]
    brush.image.fill(c) #brush is a sprite class and image is a surface
```

i have tried doing this in many ways such as:

```
def color():
    c = colorchooser.askcolor()[0]
    brush.image.fill((c[0], c[1], c[2]))
```

But it didnt work.

Here is my full code. It is probably really bad but I am somewhat new to this:

```
from pygame import * 
from tkinter import colorchooser as cl
from sys import exit

init()

width, height = 1080, 1920
screen = display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = time.Clock()

background = Surface((width * 3, height + 200))


pos = (width / 2, height / 2)
speed = 10

outline = Surface((40, 40))
outline.fill('yellow')
outrect = outline.get_rect(center = pos)
fill = Surface((30, 30))
fill.fill('dark blue')
fillrect = fill.get_rect(center = pos)

button = Surface((150, 100))
button.fill('red')
buttrect = button.get_rect(topleft = (0, 0))


Cbutton = Surface((150, 100))
Cbutton.fill('white')
Cbuttrect = button.get_rect(topleft = (150, 0))



class Player(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill('yellow')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (width / 2, height/2))
        
    
brush = Player()
brushGroup = sprite.Group()
brushGroup.add(brush)

def color():
    c = cl.askcolor()[0]
    brush.image.fill((c[0], c[1], c[2]))

while True:
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            exit()
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or e.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            pos1 = mouse.get_pos()
            
            if buttrect.collidepoint(pos1):
                brush.rect.center = (5000, 5000)
                screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            elif Cbuttrect.collidepoint(pos1):
                color()
            
            brush.rect.center = pos1
    
    brushGroup.draw(screen)
    screen.blit(button, buttrect)
    screen.blit(Cbutton, Cbuttrect)
 
    display.update()
```

And here is the full error message(I am runing this on phone so that is why the path looks like it does):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/python /game.py", line 62, in <module>
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
  File "/storage/emulated/0/python /game.py", line 48, in color
    ps.add(p)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/tkinter/colorchooser.py", line 79, in askcolor
    return Chooser(**options).show()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/tkinter/commondialog.py", line 42, in show
    w = Frame(self.master)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3134, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2576, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2543, in _setup
    master = _get_default_root()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 299, in _get_default_root
    assert _default_root is root
AssertionError
```

If someone knows how I can make this work I would be very heppy. Thnks in advance!

Comment: @SylvesterKruin i am away from home and doing this on phone to pass time with not the best net so sorry about that. here is the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/python /game.py", line 63, in <module>
    elif Cbuttrect.collidepoint(pos1):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/python /game.py", line 49, in color
Cbuttect is the button that trigers the function color

Comment: You provided the traceback (where the error came from), but you didn't provide the actual error message itself. The message itself is the line that comes ***after*** `File "/storage/emulated/0/python /game.py", line 49, in color`. Also, please _[edit] your question_ to provide the error message; don't just put it in a comment.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin here put the code and full error in the question

Comment: first you could use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables. Maybe you expect color as `(r,g,b)` but `tkinter` may gives something different.

Comment: I get this error when I close tkinter main window. When you run `colorchooser` then `tkinter` automatically creates also main window - and if you close this window then `colorchooser` can't run. You would have to manually create this window, hide it and next use `colorchooser`

Comment: other problem: if you close `colorchooser` without selectiong color then you it will return `None` and line `colorchooser.askcolor()[0]` will means `None[0]`. You should get `new_color = colorchooser.askcolor()` and later run `if new_color: color = new_color[0]`

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems which can generate errors.

**First:**

If you close `colorchooser.askcolor()` without selecting color then it will return `(None, None)` and you will have `color = (None, None)[0]` and finally you use `color = None`  and this can make problem.

You should check value

```
c = cl.askcolor()
if c[0]:  
   brush.image.fill(c[0])
```

**Second:**

When you first run `colorchooser.askcolor()` then automatically it creates main/root window because tkinter needs it.

If you close this window then next `colorchooser.askcolor()` will not create again main/root but it will raise error.

You should manually create `root` at start, and hide it - so you can't close it accidently.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_withdraw()
```

---

Working code with other changes.

I use `clock.tick(120)` to reduce speed to 120 FPS (frames per second) and use less CPU. But it may make gaps in drawing line. Normally you should remeber previous position and draw line from previous position to current position (instead fo single rectangle/point)

```
import pygame as pg    # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

import tkinter as tk   # to create main window manually 
from tkinter import colorchooser as cl

from sys import exit

# --- classes --- # PEP8: `CamelCasenames` for class names
                  # PEP8: `nouns` for class names

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill('yellow')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(width/2, height/2))  # PEP8: parameters without spaces around `=`

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for function names
                     # PEP8: `verbs` for function names

def select_color():   
    color = cl.askcolor()
    print(color)
    if color[0] is not None:
        brush.image.fill(color[0])

# --- main ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables


width, height = 1080, 1920
speed = 10

# - tkinter -

root = tk.Tk()
#root.iconify()
root.wm_withdraw()

# - pygame -

pg.init()

screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

#pos = screen_rect.center # (width/2, height/2)

background = pg.Surface((width * 3, height + 200))

outline = pg.Surface((40, 40))
outline.fill('yellow')
outline_rect = outline.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

fill = pg.Surface((30, 30))
fill.fill('dark blue')
fill_rect = fill.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

button = pg.Surface((150, 100))
button.fill('red')
button_rect = button.get_rect(topleft=(0, 0))

c_button = pg.Surface((150, 100))
c_button.fill('white')
c_button_rect = button.get_rect(topleft=(150, 0))
    
brush = Player()
brush_group = pg.sprite.Group()
brush_group.add(brush)

clock = pg.time.Clock()

while True:
    
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()  # destroy pygame window
            root.destroy() # destroy root window
            exit()
            
        #if event.type in (pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, pg.MOUSEMOTION):
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            if button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                brush.rect.center = (5000, 5000)
                screen.blit(background, (0, 0))                
            elif c_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                select_color()

        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            brush.rect.center = event.pos
            
    # - draw -

    brush_group.draw(screen)
    screen.blit(button, button_rect)
    screen.blit(c_button, c_button_rect)
 
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)   # reduce FPS to use less CPU
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)